# Needs to manually reset IIS to reflect changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, smtp

Hi I have ang MVC website wherein there are many accounts. Each account has an email address. Whenever a specific action is done, an email is sent from the email of the user to the email of another account. But whenever I change the email address of a user through the website, the email still gets sent to the old email address. I tried checking the Database and it's already updated there but still it sends to the previous e-add.

I have to do 'iisreset' in command prompt in order for the change to really take place. Can I do this without manually resetting the IIS everytime a change is made?

I hope I made myself clear, and that someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: When the DB updated, you need to apply changes to the model too (at least change the variable/property containing old address to its new value). IIS reset isn't required if you able to write code which perform value changes after saving data.

Comment: Do you store your emails in some variable/list in memory before sending?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto and how can I do that?

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal yes I store it in a string

Comment: Can you show some code? It seems like your variable does not update once fetched from DB.